# Laptop displays black screen on boot, works with external monitor, but loses display after uninstalling Nvidia graphics card

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

I encountered an issue with my laptop's display where upon booting, the screen remains black, even when attempting to access the BIOS. However, when I connected a second monitor, the external display functioned properly, allowing me to access Windows and retrieve my files.

Upon investigating the settings, I observed that the internal display was inactive, and the secondary monitor was utilizing the Nvidia graphics card. As an attempt to troubleshoot, I uninstalled the Nvidia graphics card from the Device Manager under Display adapters. However, after doing so, all monitors, including the external one, turned black, rendering the system inaccessible.

What steps can I take to resolve this issue and restore functionality to my laptop's display without relying on the external monitor?

Comment: Nothing you can do now unfortunately, other than repairing the laptop. You made the worse move possible in this situation - uninstalling the Nvidia drivers - because the external video ports typically depend on the dGPU. Take it to a professional service.

Comment: Screen did not work in BIOS and so likely a screen component gone (Display, backlight, cable, connectors)

Comment: To determine if it's the backlight, look carefully at the screen, to see if there is a **very** dim display, barely visible. If so, it's just the backlight, which often can be easily fixed, and you can access BIOS and display, albeit with difficulty, until it's fixed -- allowing reinstallation of NVIDIA driver.